# Applying for a UK visa from a Schengen country as non-resident

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, pakistani-citizens

I want to invite my grandfather from Pakistan to Europe (he has positive visa history for Schengen). As you may know most of Pakistanis living in the west reside in the UK and I would like to give him the opportunity to visit our family there.

Can he apply for a UK visa whilst being a non-resident of a Schengen country? We would like to use the service of a certified visa agent here in a Germany because the processing times are much better than in Pakistan.

Comment: Even if application from Germany is possible, it might be advisable to apply from Pakistan so he has access to any documents he might be requested to bring.